# How to add our own div instead of info window in google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, google-maps

i have shown my code below.here 5 cities showing in map.when i click marker info box is coming and showing details.here i want to add my own design(div or dialogue model box)instead of info window.how can i remove info window and add my own div or model dialogue box .any one help me out i have added my code [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLy54130/1/)

```js
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
        .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $compile) {
            
         var cities = [{
                id: '02jdjd',
                city: 'Toronto',
                desc: 'World Largest city,This city is live,This is the second best city in the world',
                lat: 43.7000,
                long: -79.4000,
                icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsss',
                city: 'New York',
                desc: 'coastal area,This city is aiiiiite, ',
                lat: 40.6700,
                long: -73.9400,
                icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsssws',
                city: 'Chicago',
                desc: 'This is the second best city in the world',
                lat: 41.8819,
                long: -87.6278,
                icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsssz',
                city: 'Los Angeles',
                desc: 'This city is live,coastal area,incredible city',
                lat: 34.0500,
                long: -118.2500,
                icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdssq',
                city: 'Las Vegas',
                desc: 'the most populous city,This city is live,This city is aiiiiite',
                lat: 36.0800,
                long: -115.1522,
                icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png'
            },
      {
                id: '6djdsss3',
                city: 'Toronto New',
                desc: 'This is the best city in the world',
                lat: 36.82220,
                long: -115.9500,
        icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'
            }
      ];


            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }

            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
         

            $scope.markers = [];

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

             


            var createMarker = function(info,i) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: $scope.map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                    title: info.city,
          icon: info.icon
                });
                marker.content = "<div><h2>"+marker.title+"</h2><input type='button' value='get' ng-click='get(\""+ info.id + "\")'/>" + "<div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.desc + "</div><div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.city + "</div><div class='bar'><div style='float: left;'><button ng-click='markerClick("+(i-1)+")'><< LEFT</button></div><div style='float: right;'><button ng-click='markerClick("+(i+1)+")'>RIGHT >></button></div></div></div>";

                google.maps.event.addListener(
                    marker,
                    'click', (function(marker, $scope) {
                        return function() {
                            var compiled = $compile(marker.content)($scope);
                            // $scope.$apply();
                            infoWindow.setContent(compiled[0]);
                            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                        };
                    })(marker, $scope)
                );

                $scope.markers.push(marker);
            }
            $scope.markerClick=function(i){

                if (i<0) i=$scope.markers.length-1;
                if (i >= $scope.markers.length) i=0;    
              
              console.log("in marker click"+i);

              google.maps.event.trigger( $scope.markers[i], 'click' );
            }
            $scope.get = function(id) {
                console.log(id);
                //alert("from $scope.get id : "+id); 
            }

            for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                createMarker(cities[i],i);
            }

            $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker) {
                e.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
            }




            $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
                    $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
                $scope.markers.length = 0;
            }



            $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
                //1.select filtered cities
                var filteredCities;
                var cityDesc = $scope.data.singleSelect;
                if (cityDesc == '0') {
                    filteredCities = cities;
                } else {
                    filteredCities = cities.filter(function(c) {
                        if (c.desc.indexOf(cityDesc) > -1)
                            return c;
                    });
                }
                //2.update markers on map
                $scope.clearMarkers();
                for (i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(filteredCities[i],i);
                }
            }

        }]);
```

```css
#map {
        height: 420px;
        width: 600px;
    }
    
    .infoWindowContent {
        font-size: 14px !important;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .bar {
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Filter Marker </label>
        <br>
        <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="filterMarkers()">
            <option value="0">all</option>
            <option value="This is the best city in the world">This is the best city in the world</option>
            <option value="This city is aiiiiite">This city is aiiiiite</option>
            <option value="the most populous city">the most populous city</option>
            <option value="This city is live">This city is live</option>
   <option value="coastal area">coastal area</option>
   <option value="World Largest city">World Largest city</option>
   <option value="incredible city">incredible city</option>
   
        </select>
        <br>
        <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
            <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So, this sounds like you want to display this information outside of the map, just in a div somewhere.  Correct?  Now, it's also possible to superimpose that div over the map, lo it looks like it's inside the map.  Obviously this div will not react to panning/zooming of the map.  Is that what you want?  Or care to elaborate in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default markers you need to use a `google.maps.OverlayView` instead. The easiest way would be to try [Google's RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/blob/gh-pages/src/richmarker.js) library.

Your *RichMarker* can have any HTML you want in it, including a tooltip / info box. You would need to add some CSS to hide your custom info box by default and some JavaScript to show it when the user clicks on your marker.

[Here's an example](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/examples/richmarker.html).